# PHPMailer not sending to all emails in mailing list

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm using the example mailing list and trying to tailor it to work with my DB. The problem I'm having is it's only sending to one email from the list of users in the Table (the example table only has 5 users). The email is being sent to the last user listed in the table

```
//Passing `true` enables PHPMailer exceptions
//$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$body = file_get_contents('contents.html');

$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER; 
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = '####'; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true; //SMTP connection will not close after each email sent, reduces SMTP overhead
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Username = '###';
$mail->Password = '###';
$mail->setFrom('###', 'List manager');
$mail->addReplyTo('###', 'List manager');

$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer Simple database mailing list test';

//Same body for all messages, so set this before the sending loop
//If you generate a different body for each recipient (e.g. you're using a templating system),
//set it inside the loop
$mail->msgHTML($body);
//msgHTML also sets AltBody, but if you want a custom one, set it afterwards
$mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!';

//Connect to the database and select the recipients from your mailing list that have not yet been sent to
//You'll need to alter this to match your database
$connection = mysqli_connect($server, $loginsql, $passsql, "database_name")
                or die("Could not connect to database");

$result = mysqli_query($connection, 'SELECT user_login, user_email, db_prefix FROM userstest');

foreach ($result as $row) {
    try {
        $mail->addAddress($row['user_email'], $row['user_login']);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Invalid address skipped: ' . htmlspecialchars($row['user_email']) . '<br>';
        continue;
    }
    try {
        $mail->send();
        echo 'Message sent to :' . htmlspecialchars($row['user_email']) . ' (' .
            htmlspecialchars($row['user_email']) . ')<br>';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Mailer Error (' . htmlspecialchars($row['user_email']) . ') ' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '<br>';
        //Reset the connection to abort sending this message
        //The loop will continue trying to send to the rest of the list
        $mail->getSMTPInstance()->reset();
    }
    //Clear all addresses and attachments for the next iteration
    $mail->clearAddresses();
    $mail->clearAttachments();
}
```

Comment: First off: Did you check the junk/spam mail boxes of all recipients ?

Comment: @KenLee Yes. I also updated my comment to say it's actually only sending to the last listed row in the table

Comment: Can you confirm you are seeing multiple instances of 'Message sent to :...', and they each contain a different email address?

Comment: I see no obvious issue here, as your code is almost the same as the sample from PHPMailer git (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps).  Turn on debug (`$mail->SMTPDebug = 4;`) and look at logs.  Add debug messages in your loop for calls to addAddress and see if they are all called like expected.  You might need to send your emails to 1 "to" address and the rest as "cc" or "bcc".

Comment: One key thing: you wrote a load of exception handling, but then commented out the instantiating line that enables exceptions, so they will never trigger.

Comment: @kmoser yes I can confirm that there script prints out multiple lines of "message sent to" all with the different email addresses in each row of the table

Comment: @Synchro I've just enabled it and it still only sends the one email

Comment: @Nic3500 I've added the debug and all looks fine. I changed the addAddress to addCC and it still only sends to the one address. The mail that was received on that one account even lists all the other emails in the CC field.... yet they never received the email

Comment: If you can see it issuing `RCPT TO` SMTP commands, yet those addresses are not receiving your messages, it’s a mail server problem, not anything in PHPMailer or your script. You need to check your mail server’s log to find out what’s happening to your messages.

Answer (score 0):

All - thanks for the help. I actually figured it out. The email address for  setFrom was not the same as the account that was sending it out so it wouldn't work sending out to external domains.